# Translate lists to a 2D numpy matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have a list of lists in python. The lists is the following:

```
[[196, 242, 3], 
 [186, 302, 3], 
 [22, 377, 1],
 [196, 377, 3],
 ....
 ]
```

The first column correspond to users (1:943) and the second to items(1:1682) and their votes to items. I want to try the matrix factorization [library](https://github.com/mnick/scikit-tensor). Should I created a users x items matrix? If yes how can I create a matrix like that in python, with the one axis to be in size of users the other one the size of items and the values the votes of the users?

**EDIT:** I check also the implementation of nmf.py which requir as input a 2D matrix and not a list or a sparse represantation.

Comment: I assume not every combination occurs, so search for sparse matrices...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You data looks like a list of lists:

```
In [168]: ll = [[196, 242, 3], 
     ...:  [186, 302, 3], 
     ...:  [22, 377, 1],
     ...:  [196, 377, 3]]
```

Make an array from it - for convenience in the following operations

```
In [169]: A = np.array(ll)
In [170]: ll
Out[170]: [[196, 242, 3], [186, 302, 3], [22, 377, 1], [196, 377, 3]]
In [171]: A
Out[171]: 
array([[196, 242,   3],
       [186, 302,   3],
       [ 22, 377,   1],
       [196, 377,   3]])
```

Shift the index columns to 0 base (optional)

```
In [172]: A[:,:2] -= 1
```

With this it is quick and easy define a sparse matrix using the `coo` (or `csr`) format, of `(data, (rows, cols))`.  The iterative `dok` approach works, but this is faster.

```
In [174]: from scipy import sparse
In [175]: M = sparse.csr_matrix((A[:,2],(A[:,0], A[:,1])), shape=(942,1681))
In [176]: M
Out[176]: 
<942x1681 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int32'>'
    with 4 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [177]: print(M)
  (21, 376) 1
  (185, 301)    3
  (195, 241)    3
  (195, 376)    3
```

`M.A` creates a dense array from this sparse matrix.  Some code, especially in the `sckit-learn` package can use sparse matrices directly.

A direct way of creating the dense array is:

```
In [183]: N = np.zeros((942,1681),int)
In [184]: N[A[:,0],A[:,1]]= A[:,2]
In [185]: N.shape
Out[185]: (942, 1681)
In [186]: M.A.shape
Out[186]: (942, 1681)
In [187]: np.allclose(N, M.A)   # it matches the sparse version
Out[187]: True
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure.

You can create a 2-dimensional numpy array (which you can treat as a matrix), using the [`np.array`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html) function:

```
mat = np.array(list_of_lists)
```

Comment: Yes I want to factorize the matrix and not the tuples that I have in the beginning, So I need to create o matrix with users x items

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can create a sparse matrix from the list of set items:

```
data = [
    [196, 242, 3], 
    [186, 302, 3], 
    [22, 377, 1],
    [196, 377, 3],
    ....
]

user_count = max(i[0] for i in data) + 1
item_count = max(i[1] for i in data) + 1

data_mx = scipy.sparse.dok_matrix((user_count, item_count))
for (user, item, value) in data:
    data_mx[user, item] = value
```

Comment: So I can use the sparse data_mx directly or still I have to transform it as a normal array matrix?

Comment: How can I use the sparse represantation of the decomposition. All the code I found is for 2D matrix.